# Transitioning the :after CSS selector

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS3 transition for :after pseudoelement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922022/css3-transition-for-after-pseudoelement)

Is it possible to transition the `:after` selector using CSS3 transitions?
At the moment I'm trying to transition a border but with no success.

### CSS

```
.selector:after{
    display:block;
    border:5px solid transparent;
    position:absolute;
    top:-5px;
    left:-5px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    content: '';
    pointer-events:none;
    -webkit-transition:border-color .5s linear;
    -moz-transition:border-color .5s linear;
    -o-transition:border-color .5s linear;
    -ms-transition:border-color .5s linear;
    transition:border-color .5s linear;
}

.selector:hover:after{
    border-color: #bf0add;
    border-radius:5px;
    z-index:99;
}
```

Comment: I don't know for sure if this would work, but have you tried .selector:after:hover instead?

Comment: hey, this works in terms of displaying the border on hover, only problem is that the transition doesnt seem to work

Comment: Maybe see if transition: all .5s linear; would do it. If not, this may be a limitation of CSS animations. One that gets me every time is that background gradients can't transition.

Answer (score 0):

Transition/Animation on CSS generated content is not supported yet. You can use the following link to keep track for its future support: http://css-tricks.com/transitions-and-animations-on-css-generated-content/